# wordpress api using rest_route for other pages

Tags: permalinks, urls, rest-api, http

Ok, so I am using WordPress rest API to fetch the data using front-end. I am having the plain permalinks and unfortunately, I am not allowed to change the permalinks. 
So, for

```
https://www.example.com
```

I am using the route option:

```
https://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts
```

And this is working completely fine.

Now my question is if I want to access a page URL with query params :

```
https://www.example.com?cat=12
```

How could I do that with rest_route? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I was able to figure out with a little modification to Rank's answer:

```
https://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&categories=12
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the parameters at the end, so it is defined which data should be affected. You add it after the 'post' to get all posts within the category with the id of 12.

`https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=12`

Comment: I tried this 
https://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/?cat=12 
But it shows "No route was found matching the URL and request method". 
The page https://www.example.com?cat=12 does exist

Comment: I took out the '/' character, so if you like you could accept my answer, as it solved your issue. Thank you!